# Pythonic way for checking if value exists in dictionary of dictionaries and taking corresponding actions

Tags: python

I have created a dictionary of dictionaries as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
```

Now I have some strings (let us call this set `A`) which have a dictionary of strings (as key) and integers (as value) corresponding to it. So the above data structure models this data completely.

Now I want to check if a string corresponding to a key in `A` exists in the dictionary. If it does not exist I want to add it and make its counter `1`. If it already exists, I want to increment the counter.

Is there is pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: "*which have a dictionary of strings(as key)*": how? I thought dictionaries were unhashable.

Comment: @Blender `>>> d=defaultdict(dict)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {})
` SO I thought that this is key. I am new to python so do not know in much detail. I should have mode a mistake there, not sure.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam the `defaultdict(dict)` has `dict` as *values*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the key to the nested `dict`, you can use a simple `in` test:

```
if somestring in d[key]:
    d[key][somestring] += 1
else:
    d[key][somestring] = 1
```

but you could use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
d = defaultdict(Counter)

d[key][somestring] += 1
```

Like a `defaultdict`, a `Counter` provides a default value for missing keys, defaulting to `0`.

Counters have other benefits; instead of looping over a set of strings and manually increasing the counter for those one by one, pass the whole sequence to the `.update()` method for the appropriate counter:

```
d[key].update(sequence_of_strings)
```

and the `Counter` will count them all for you.

The `Counter` class is what other languages might call a Multi-Set or Bag type. They support interesting comparison and arithmetic operations too, do make sure you read the documentation for the type.

Comment: Will `d[key][somestring] += 1` take care if `d[key][somestring]` does not exist but `d[key]` is already present.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: With a Counter it will, yes. It will work even if `d[key]` is not yet present.

Answer (score 1):

As Lev Levitsky pointed out, what you want is to use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). For example, assuming that you have this strings:

```
>>> the_strings = [
...     ('a', ('the', 'strings', 'in', 'the', 'dict')),
...     ('b', ('other', 'strings', 'in', 'the', 'dict', 'in', 'your', 'question'))
... ]
```

And you want to associate to `'a'` a dict with the counts of that words, you can do:

```
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for key, strings in the_strings:
...     my_dict[key].update(strings)
... 
>>> my_dict['a']['the']
2
>>> my_dict['b']['in']
2
>>> my_dict['b']['question']
1
```

If you want to increase a single value you can simply do:

```
>>> my_dict[the_string][the_word] += 1
```

Or you can automatically increase the count of every element in an iterable using the [`update`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) method:

```
>>> my_dict[the_string].update(iterable_of_elements)
```